# Check If There is HTML in input

Tags: php, xss

I have a textarea where user can add something. To avoid inserting HTML  i use following `PHP functions` on textarea?

```
$text = addslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'])));
```

A message from the user is looks like in the DB like below.

```
8KsAtP  &lt;a href=&quot;http://lqexajgwyrsk.com/&quot;&gt;lqexajgwyrsk&lt;/a&gt;,
[url=http://imndawriqhnk.com/]imndawriqhnk[/url],
[link=http://qyozfozrqier.com/]qyozfozrqier[/link],
http://oykrvybeqata.com/
```

**My Question** is that how can i check there is HTML code in textarea, instead of inserting it in DB like above i want to show error message.

My Question is different to [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) in the way that I am asking how to check if there is html or link in field. and answer on this question how can i check is also provided by **Dale**. While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) is asking about how to prevent. and i already use functions given in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Comment: That's the wrong order `strip_tags` will have nothing to strip because `htmlspecialchars` will have converted all tags to their entities. Use the `htmlspecialchars` on output, and encode the quotes as well.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php , and http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

```
// check there is no html content
if(strip_tags($_POST['message']) == $_POST['message']) {
    // continue to process
} else {
    // there is html in the message
}
```